Bisection method of trigonometric functions in python
I don't know the bisection method of range. So, the wrong range make a infinite loop.
import math
import numpy as np

iteration = 0
eps = 1.0e-5 # the residual tolerance

x_upper =-np.pi/5
x_lower =-2*np.pi/5

guess = (x_upper + x_lower)*0.5 # Set guess as the mid point
eps = 1.0e-2
residual = - np.tan(guess) + 1/np.exp(guess) - 2.0
converged = math.fabs(residual) < eps

while not(converged):
    residual = - np.tan(guess) + 1/np.exp(guess) - 2.0
    print(guess)
    if (residual < 0):
        x_lower = guess
        print(guess)
    else:
        x_upper = guess
        print(guess)
    guess = (x_upper + x_lower) * 0.5
    converged = math.fabs(residual) < eps
    iteration += 1
    print(guess)


print("x =",guess)
print("LHS of the equation =",- np.tan(guess) + 1/np.exp(guess))
print("It took",iteration,"guesses to get that answer")

I try fixing by changing a range. But still infinite loop.

Converging means that the difference between the current iteration and the previous one is lower than some threshold. You are just checking if your error gets below a certain threshold. That's not what convergence is. The loop is infinite because for a certain guess -1.2566370614359172 the upper_bound that you calculate gives the same guess. The program correctly converges, since the current iteration guess is the same as the previous iteration guess
